# together jnlp and DLL - I want downloadable dll

Tags: java, jnlp

I've just created jnlp file.  For testing reason, codebase="".  in the folder, where jnlp file is, I have also Myjar.jar, and f.dll.

and in JNLP resource

```
<resources>
    <j2se version="1.6+" href="http://java.sun.com/products/autodl/j2se"/>
    <jar href="MyJar.jar" main="true" />
</resources>
```

**Everything works!**

**QUESTION.**

if I change codebase, my jar will be downloaded , but, I want dll to be downloaded too, because,  Myjar.jar needs it.... how can I do that?.. what do you think?...

Answer (score 0):

You put the dll file in a separate, **signed** jar file that is shipped along with main application.

Here's another, more specific question, which, however, has a great example of doing what you need: [Java Webstart with Tibco Native Libs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1399397/java-webstart-with-tibco-native-libs)

Answer (score 0):

Pack up your dll in a signed jar and include this jar into the jnlp-File using the "nativelib"-tag as decribed in the [JNLP-syntax documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/javaws/developersguide/syntax.html#resources).